# retrieve values inside foreach loop and for loop

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, foreach, nested

I would like to call a function inside a forEach loop to display datas but the problem is that I must do again a for loop inside the forEach loop to access other elements and so if I put the my call of the function inside the forEach loop, other elements are not called and if I put the function inside the for loop (that is inside the foreach loop) the elements are displayed twice. Could you please help me ?
Here is my code :

```js
const data = [{
    "restaurantName": "Bronco",
    "address": "39 Rue des Petites Écuries, 75010 Paris",
    "lat": 48.8737815,
    "long": 2.3501649,
    "ratings": [{
        "stars": 4,
        "comment": "Un excellent restaurant, j'y reviendrai !Par contre il vaut mieux aimer la viande."
      },
      {
        "stars": 5,
        "comment": "Tout simplement mon restaurant préféré !"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "restaurantName": "Babalou",
    "address": "4 Rue Lamarck, 75018 Paris",
    "lat": 48.8865035,
    "long": 2.3442197,
    "ratings": [{
        "stars": 5,
        "comment": "Une minuscule pizzeria délicieuse cachéejuste à côté du Sacré choeur !"
      },
      {
        "stars": 3,
        "comment": "J'ai trouvé ça correct, sans plus"
      }
    ]
  }
]


data.forEach((element) => {
  const name = element.restaurantName;
  const address = element.address;

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const comment = element.ratings[i].comment;
    const stars = element.ratings[i].stars;

  }
  init_resto(name, address, comment, stars);

})



var list_group = document.getElementById('list-group');

function init_resto(name, address, comment, stars) {
  var liElt = document.createElement('li');

  liElt.innerHTML =
    "<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + name + "</li>" +
    "<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + address + "</li>" +
    "<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + comment + "</li>" +
    "<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + stars + "</li>";
  list_group.appendChild(liElt);
}
```

```html
<ul id="list-group"></ul>
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I made you a [mcve] - it gives an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const data = [{ "restaurantName": "Bronco", "address": "39 Rue des Petites Écuries, 75010 Paris", "lat": 48.8737815, "long": 2.3501649, "ratings": [{ "stars": 4, "comment": "Un excellent restaurant, j'y reviendrai !Par contre il vaut mieux aimer la viande." }, { "stars": 5, "comment": "Tout simplement mon restaurant préféré !" } ] }, { "restaurantName": "Babalou", "address": "4 Rue Lamarck, 75018 Paris", "lat": 48.8865035, "long": 2.3442197, "ratings": [{ "stars": 5, "comment": "Une minuscule pizzeria délicieuse cachéejuste à côté du Sacré choeur !" }, { "stars": 3, "comment": "J'ai trouvé ça correct, sans plus" } ] } ];

const formatData = data => {
  document.getElementById('list-group').innerHTML = data
    .map(({restaurantName,address,ratings}) => // only take these 3 members of the array
    `<li class="list-group-item">${restaurantName}</li>
     <li class="list-group-item">${address}</li>
     <li class="list-group-item">
       <ul>
         ${ratings                   // embedded variable 
          .map(({stars,comment}) =>  // map 
            `<li>${comment}</li>     // with nested template literals
            <li>${"*****".slice(-stars)}</li>`
          ).join("")}
       </ul>
     </li>`
   ).join(""); // map returns an array, so join using empty string
};
 
//fetch("http://localhost/ApiMap/data.json")
// .then((response) => response.json())
// .then(formaData(data));
formatData(data); // remove and uncomment above when happy
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list-group"></ul>
```

Comment: Finally I took yours ;) could you explain me what does $ means in your code ?

Comment: Template literals are strings in `\`` backticks. When you want to include a variable or a statement in the template literal, you wrap it in `${....}`  -  you can nest them as I did. I will update the answer with comments

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you want it to be displayed.

Pass through the ratings as an array and then loop over them as a list within a list?

```
data.forEach((element) => {
    const name = element.restaurantName;
    const address = element.address;
    const ratings = element.ratings;

    init_resto(name, address, ratings);
    
});
```

Ensure the ratings have a default (just encase)

```
function init_resto(name, address, ratings = []) {
  var liElt = document.createElement('li');

  liElt.innerHTML =
    "<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + name + "</li>" +
    "<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + address + "</li>" +
    "<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + init_ratings(ratings) + "</li>"
  list_group.appendChild(liElt);
}

function init_ratings(ratings) {
    var styledRatings = ratings.map(rating => {
        return "<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + rating.comment + "</li>" 
            + "<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + rating.stars + "</li>" 
      })
    return "<ul>" + styledRatings.join('') + "</ul>";
}
```